# Using System.Net.Ping in UWP app - VS 2017

Tags: c#, uwp, nuget, ping, visual-studio-2017

I added the `System.Net.Ping` NuGet Package to a blank UWP project and referenced the `System.Net.NetworkInformation` namespace in `Mainpage.xaml.cs`.

In the MainPage constructor I just wrote `Ping ping = new Ping()`.

Compiling this simple example throws this exception upon launch:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Ping, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Net.Ping, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at App2.MainPage..ctor()
   at App2.App2_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.Activate_0_MainPage()
   at App2.App2_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance()
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame.Navigate(Type sourcePageType, Object parameter)
   at App2.App.OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)}  System.IO.FileNotFoundException
```

The NuGet package `System.Net.Ping` is currently available in version 4.3.0 and 4.0.0, but both of those behaved the same.

Comment: When I try to repro this the restore fails saying that the package doesn't have the proper UAP components... which would explain why nothing restores and you cannot find the assembly at run time. Perhaps I'm confused about your scenario?

Comment: Any solution to this problem found? 
I'm stepping into the same problem - installed V 4.3.0 while the exception is referencing to V 4.0.0

Comment: @Christoph No, sorry. I ended up not using UWP for my Szenario at all. Since this was supposed to run on a Raspberry Pi with Windows 10 IoT Core, I was able to fulfill my needs by just using Raspbian instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the date of this answer, the class `System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping` is not yet supported on UWP platform. Check [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/45e75273-2b87-44cd-86f8-84eb8b285a05/uwpcusing-systemnetping-in-uwp-app-vs-2017?forum=wpdevelop) for details.

Comment: Huh, I completely forgot about asking the same question on MSDN as well, and apparently didn't get notified of the, now almost 1 year old, answer.

Thanks for bringing that to my attention I guess :D

Comment: :-) Actually I wasn't really sure that author was the same on both posts, so I thought helpful to share the answer here too.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding reference to System.Net.Utilities instead of System.Net.Ping

Comment: Throws pretty much the exact same exception, just with `System.Net.Utilities` instead of `System.Net.Ping`.